# Trying to build a custom directive in angularjs with more than one property in the controller without using scope in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a custom directive in angularJS.

This is my Javascript code.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("myController", [function () {
    this.naomi = { name: 'naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    this.igor = { name: 'igor', address: 'Amphitheatre 1600' }
}])
.directive("myCustomer", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'ACE',
        scope:{
            customerinfo:'='
        },
        controller: 'myController',
        controllerAs: 'Cntrl',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl:'CustomerDetails2.html'
    }
})
```

Here is my HTML part.

Main HTML Page:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as Cntrl">
    <my-customer customerinfo="naomi"></my-customer>
    <my-customer customerinfo="igor"></my-customer>
</body>
```

CustomerDetails2.html:

```
Name:<b>{{Cntrl.customerinfo.name}}</b> address:<b>{{Cntrl.customerinfo.address}}</b>
```

When the HTML page rendered, the angular binding was not working. Following is the view that's getting rendered in the browser.

[RENDERED HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpCB0.png)

Can anyone tell me how to achieve the binding here without using $scope dependency in the controller.

Comment: 6 answers, no upvote for you :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The directive attribute should not be in camel case.
- In your template, the reference to `Cntrl` to be removed

**Run the below working snippet**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("myController", [
    function() {
      this.naomi = {
        name: 'naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
      };
      this.igor = {
        name: 'igor',
        address: 'Amphitheatre 1600'
      }
    }
  ])
  .directive("myCustomer", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'ACE',
      scope: {
        customerInfo: '='
      },
      controller: 'myController',
      controllerAs: 'Cntrl',
      template: 'Name:<b>{{customerInfo.name}}</b> address:<b>{{customerInfo.address}}</b>'
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as Cntrl">
  <my-customer customer-info="Cntrl.naomi"></my-customer>
  <my-customer customer-info="Cntrl.igor"></my-customer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use camel case in your view

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as Cntrl">
    <my-customer customer-info="naomi"></my-customer>
    <my-customer customer-info="igor"></my-customer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.

First is the camel case in your attributes names, they have to be dash separated.

The second is in your controller and main view your using `controller as` syntax but not utilizing it (see your bindings:):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as Cntrl">
    <my-customer customer-info="Cntrl.naomi"></my-customer>
    <my-customer customer-info="Cntrl.igor"></my-customer>
</div>
```

Without this your not passing anything into the `customer-info` binding.

---

Finally in your directive you have a controller which is access the controllers scope with controller as but also passing in a variable on the directives scope.

However your syntax for accessing either is wrong.

Either use the controller as to access your variables or the scope property:

```
.directive("myCustomer", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'ACE',
        scope:{
            customerInfo:'='
        },
        controller: 'myController',
        controllerAs: 'Cntrl',
        bindToController: true,
        template:'{{Cntrl}}</br>customer info: {{customerInfo}}'
    }
});
```

I'm not entirely sure how angular works here, it apepars like theres two scopes `customerInfo` and the scope from the controller `Cntrl` I would have to research exactly what happening here but i would use one or the other, not both. Either access things from your controller and get rid of the attribute, or just pass things into the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Let's combine answer above (below?) to actually make it work.

You must use `Cntrl` prefix because you have used `as` in your HTML.
You must always use camel case in JavaScript, dash separated counterpart in HTML.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as Cntrl">
  <my-customer customer-info="Cntrl.naomi"></my-customer>
  <my-customer customer-info="Cntrl.igor"></my-customer>
</body>
```

In JavaScript, drop the `controller`, `bindToController` and `controllerAs` from directive. You want to bind to isolated scope, not controller.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', [function () {
    this.naomi = { name: 'naomi', address: '1600 Amphitheatre' };
    this.igor = { name: 'igor', address: 'Amphitheatre 1600' };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            customerInfo:'='
        },
        templateUrl:  'CustomerDetails2.html'
    };
});
```

Same applies to your directive template

```
Name:<b>{{customerInfo.name}}</b> address:<b>{{customerInfo.address}}</b>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to use dash for your attributes, and in the directive use camelCase
2. if you use controller as you need to use the alias to access params `Cntrl.naomi`

Here is an example for creating a directive:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("myController", ['$scope',
    function() {
      this.naomi = {
        name: 'naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
      };
      this.igor = {
        name: 'igor',
        address: 'Amphitheatre 1600'
      }
    }
  ])
  .directive("myCustomer", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AEC',
      scope: {
        customerInfo: '='
      },
      template: 'Name:<b>{{customerInfo.name}}</b> address:<b>{{customerInfo.address}}</b>'
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as Cntrl">
  <my-customer customer-info="Cntrl.naomi"></my-customer>
  <my-customer customer-info="Cntrl.igor"></my-customer>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

please change your code to something like this

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as Cntrl">
<my-customer customerInfo="Cntrl.naomi"></my-customer>
<my-customer customerInfo="Cntrl.igor"></my-customer>
</body>
```

your are using controller as syntax so you should refer controller variables with Cntrl.